# Usage of variables in an UPDATE (edited)

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

Consider this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_and_replace_everywhere(regex TEXT,
                                                         replacement TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    matching search_columns_result;
BEGIN
    FOR matching IN SELECT *
                    FROM search_columns(regex)
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'schemaname: %s, tablename: %s, columnname: %s, rowctid: %s', quote_ident(matching.schemaname), quote_ident(matching.tablename), quote_ident(matching.columnname), quote_ident(matching.rowctid);
            UPDATE ${matching.schemaname}.${matching.tablename} SET ${matching.columnname} = REPLACE(${matching.columnname}, regex, replacement);
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How am I supposed to write this UPDATE ? I can't find a way to insert variable value inside query to build it.

EDIT, I think I find the way ! But I still miss something because :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_and_replace_everywhere(regex TEXT,
                                                         replacement TEXT)
    RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    matching search_columns_result;
BEGIN
    FOR matching IN SELECT *
                    FROM search_columns(regex)
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'schemaname: %s, tablename: %s, columnname: %s, rowctid: %s', QUOTE_IDENT(matching.schemaname), QUOTE_IDENT(matching.tablename), QUOTE_IDENT(matching.columnname), QUOTE_IDENT(matching.rowctid);
            EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET %I = REPLACE(%I, %I, %I)', matching.schemaname || '.' || matching.tablename,
                           matching.columnname, matching.columnname, regex, replacement);
        END LOOP;
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

generates :

> ERROR:  relation "public.groups_oxusers" does not exist LINE 1: UPDATE
>   "public.groups_oxusers" SET group_name = REPLACE(grou...

Why is there double quotes around table name but not around column name and how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two placeholders for schema and tablename, not one. And the parameters should be passed with the `USING` clause:

```
EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I.%I SET %I = REPLACE(%I, $2, $3)', 
                matching.schemaname, 
                matching.tablename,
                matching.columnname,
                matching.columnname)
  USING regex, replacement;
```